# How do I use XMLHttpRequest in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, xmlhttprequest

This is a new situation for me, I have been using TypeScript for a long time but struggling with `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
request.open('GET', path);
request.onload = () => {
   // this is fine
}
request.onerror = (e: ErrorEvent) => {
   // i can't figure this out
   this.registerError(e);
}
```

How do I correctly deal with that error response?  My code above fails during compilation with this:

error TS2322: Type `(e: ErrorEvent) => void` is not assignable to type `(this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: ProgressEvent) => any`

I wasn't expecting that.

If you change the code to

```
request.onerror = (this: XMLHttpRequest, ev: ProgressEvent) => {
};
```

It isn't valid typescript. Even if it was, `this` as a parameter name is incredibly confusing.

**Would it be possible to provide an example of how to catch an XMLHttpRequest error?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you can't specify `this` is because you are using an arrow function `=>`. You just need to change the type of the parameter:

```
request.onerror = (e: ProgressEvent) => {

}
```

You don't really need to specify the type at all as it is inferred based on the type of `onerror`

```
request.onerror = (e) => {
    e // is  ProgressEvent
}
```

If you use a regular function you can specify `this`

```
request.onerror = function(this: XMLHttpRequest, e: ProgressEvent) {
     this // is XMLHttpRequest
}
```

Although you don't really need to as it will be implicitly typed based on the type of `onerror`

```
request.onerror = function(e: ProgressEvent) {
     this // is still XMLHttpRequest
}
```